# Azure generate_blob_sas TypeError

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-blob-storage, typeerror

I am using the Azure Blob Storage `python` SDK and trying to generate a sas token for my blob, however I keep getting a `TypeError`.

This is how I'm calling the built-in function (`generate_blob_sas`).

```
sas_blob = generate_blob_sas(account_name= account_name, 
                            container_name= container_name,
                            blob_name= blob,
                            account_key= account_key,
                            #For writing back to the Azure Blob set write and create to True 
                            permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True, write= False, create= False),
                            #This URL will be valid for 2 hour
                            expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=2))
```

I am quite sure all the input variables are correct, as I have used them all throughout my app for other functions provided by the SDK.

The error I am getting is this:

```
"TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable"
```

I am wondering if anyone has come across this when using the python SDK for Azure Blob or if anyone has any suggestions on what might help.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, The code that you have provided works fine whereas you are receiving `"TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable"` because at some point of code you are trying to convert a "set" type object into JSON. Since the JSON encoder handles **list** values, you can use the list while converting. You can refer [Borislav Hadzhiev's - Object of type set is not JSON serializable](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-typeerror-object-of-type-set-is-not-json-serializable) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a problem with my environment variables in the end. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).